# C program terminates without any error after execution of scanf() and taking the input from user

Tags: c, scanf

Program terminates automatically after the execution of `scanf()` and taking input from the user.

This is a program to print perfect number in a given range

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i, n, j, sum;
    printf("enter the number \n ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            if (n % j == 0) {
                sum += j;
            }
        }
        if (sum == n) {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }   
}
```

[execution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcSKD.png)

Comment: Print the values of `sum` and `i` at the end of the loop.

Comment: @saurabhkansyakar: I rolled back your changes: you are not supposed to correct the code in the question from the answers and comments, it make these irrelevant and confusing.

Comment: saurabh kansyakar, what is the maximum `n` expected? `INT_MAX`?

Comment: @chux: good catch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple typos in your code:

- you must stop the inner loop **before** `j`, not `i <= j`
- you must compute `i % j`, not `n % j`
- you must test `if (sum == i)`, not `if (sum == n)`
- you should print a newline after the number to separate the perfect numbers.
- to search in a range, you must prompt for its boundaries

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, start, end, j, sum;

    printf("enter the range: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &start, &end) != 2)
        return 1;
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                sum += j;
            }
        }
        if (sum == i) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    // uncomment this if running from an IDE
    //scanf("%*s");
    return 0;
}
```

If your *compiler still terminates* after the `scanf()`, chances you are running your program from within an IDE that does not leave the terminal window open after execution. You can add an extra `scanf("%*s");` before the `return 0;` statement at the end of `main()` to make the program wait for more input.

Comment: thanks for this code ,i corrected my code but here you are just finding whether a number is perfect or not but i want to print all the perfect number in a given range

Comment: Your program did not do that either. If you want to restrict the search to a given range, you must ask for the range boundaries. The above code searches in the range [1..n]

Comment: thanks a lot for this

Comment: can you point out the problem in this code,in my compiler it also terminates after scanf  #include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i,n,count=0;
    printf("enter the number \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==2)
    {
        printf("the number is prime \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not prime \n");
    }
}

Comment: @saurabhkansyakar: I just updated my answer with a potential expanation

Comment: @saurabhkansyakar [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309400/c-program-terminates-without-any-error-after-execution-of-scanf-and-taking-the/60309979#comment106682752_60309686) is another question and deserves to be posted elsewhere - even if it is a dupe of code attempting of `n%0`.

Answer (score 1):

**Performance tip - Perfect numbers**

Presently code is O(n*n), which can take a long time for large `n`.

A significant speed up is to only iterate division attempts up to the sqrt(i), thus O(n*sqrt(n))

```
    sum = 1;
    // for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
    for (j = 2; j < i/j; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
        sum += j;   // Add both factors: j, i/j
        sum += i/j;
      }
    }
    if (j == i/j) {  
      if (i % j == 0) { // perfect square?
        sum += j;  // Add 1 factor
      }
    }
    if (sum == i && i > 1) {
      printf("%d\n", i);
    }
```

---

Even faster methods exist.  More info [Perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

Comment: @chqrlie Yep - re-work done.

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason is that with input `100`, `sum` never be `100` so there will be no `printf` execution.

If you were to print the sum at the end of the outer `for` loop you would see this:

```
enter the number 
 100
sum:1
sum:3
sum:3
sum:7
sum:12
sum:12
sum:12
sum:12
sum:12
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:22
sum:42
sum:42
sum:42
sum:42
sum:42
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:67
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:117
sum:217
```

Comment: thanks i corrected my code but problem is still there